# Finding coefficients of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $n$ be a natural number. Let $f(x)=\prod_{i=-n}^{n}(x-i)$.
If $k$ is an even integer, then the coefficient of $x^k$ is zero. The coefficient of $x^{2n-1}$ is $-(1^2+\cdots+n^2)=-\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. It is easy to see that the sum of all coefficients is zero. How about the rest of coefficients? Is there any explicit formula for them?

Let $g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{x-1}$. What are the coefficient of $g(x)$?

Comment: The next coefficient is $\frac{1}{360} n (n^2 - 1) (4 n^2 - 1) (5 n + 6)$. This follows from it being equal to $\sum_{i>j}i^2j^2$ which can be evaluated from considering $(\sum i^2)^2 = 2\sum_{i>j} i^2j^2 + \sum i^4$

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients of a polynomial given by its roots are given by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

These formulas express the coefficients as elementary symmetric functions of the roots.

In your case it may be simpler to write $f(x)=x\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x^2-i^2)=xh(x^2)$, where $h(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-i^2)$, and apply Vieta's formulas to $h$.

The actual coefficients seem to be given by [A008955](https://oeis.org/A008955).

Comment: Actually I tried to use Vieta's formulas, but they don't help to find the coefficient explicitly, as far as I know.